# Laravel Mix ^1.0 (Unexpected token } in JSON at position 26)

Tags: laravel-mix

I am trying to use Laravel Mix in my Laravel Project and just setting up using this configuration:

Laravel Mix : `^1.0`

**webpack.mix.js**

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix
    .js('resources/assets/admin/js/app.js', 'public/assets/admin');
```

Running `npm run dev` i am getting this error:

```
$ npm run dev

> @ dev c:\Users\user\laravel
> npm run development


> @ development c:\Users\user\laravel
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress
--hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

undefined:3
}
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token } in JSON at position 26
    at Object.parse (native)
    at babelrc (c:\Users\user\laravel\node_modules\l
aravel-mix\src\config.js:212:36)
    at global.tap (c:\Users\user\laravel\node_module
s\laravel-mix\src\helpers.js:10:5)
    at Object.babel (c:\Users\user\laravel\node_modu
les\laravel-mix\src\config.js:210:13)
    at module.exports (c:\Users\user\laravel\node_mo
dules\laravel-mix\src\builder\webpack-rules.js:15:33)
    at WebpackConfig.buildRules (c:\Users\user\laravel\node_modules\laravel-mix\src\builder\WebpackConfig.js:81:41)
    at WebpackConfig.build (c:\Users\user\laravel\no
de_modules\laravel-mix\src\builder\WebpackConfig.js:25:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Users\user\laravel\nod
e_modules\laravel-mix\setup\webpack.config.js:26:38)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at requireConfig (c:\Users\user\laravel\node_mod
ules\webpack\bin\convert-argv.js:97:18)
```

I am not sure about this error. It seems like the error is with the laravel-mix source code but when i upgrade to `1.6` also i am getting the same error.

Also i have added and removed all the codes in my `app.js` but the error is same.

**Note:**

It works with `0.8` version though.

Comment: Looks like a syntax error in your js

Comment: @Nartub I have an empty `app.js`. So, there is nothing to compile and throw error on.